# neo4j graphaware php-client: class not found

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

When I tray to access my neo4j-DB via Graphaware's php-client using http-protocol, I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'GraphAware\Common\Result\AbstractRecordCursor' not found in ...

On the other hand when I'm using the bolt-protocol t says:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method GraphAware\Bolt\Result\Result::getResult() in...

At the beginning of my code I have used

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;
```

so I thought the classes should be autoloaded which is obviously not the case.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by replacing the respective syntax for queries of the example-files by one out of the README.